# Change cell colors based on value, where there are single cell and multiple cells changes

Tags: excel, vba, calendar, background-color

I'm creating a calendar style schedule for students.

We have many classes, so to ease the schedule, I made a Sunday start calendar form and those classes in calendar make by dependent dropdown.
e.g. Horizontally three levels, first level "Beginner", second level "AndroidSmartphone", third "Camera".

Hence, I have to change cell colors based on specific single cell values and apply to multiple cells.

And perhaps users will enter multiple values to sheets, for example whole day; 1, 2, 3, periods, same classes.

And users may change one's mind and delete those classes's values at once, in this case may 3 by 3 cells would be deleted.

The following code shows me error code 13.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim trlRed As Long
    Dim adrBlue As Long
    
    trlRed = RGB(230, 37, 30)
    adrBlue = RGB(126, 199, 216)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M31:AM53")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value = "Session" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Trial" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = trlRed 

            ElseIf cell.Value = "AndroidSmartphone" And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "trial" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = adrBlue
            Else
                cell.Resize(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to create the sheet that can dynamically change cell colors based on value, single cell, multiple cell, and delete values also.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you should add input and expected output. Anyways, did you try Conditional formatting?

Comment: Code runs perfectly in testing. What did you do to get the error 13?

Comment: I appreciate your advice, i tried conditional formatting, however, there are too many pattern due to tons of workshops varieties. And there was demand to change color when new workshop came. Using conditional formatting cannt handle those situation.

Comment: Plutian san, I appreciate your attention.
My original code has some issues when value deleted. Didn't you get error code 13?

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks if any cells in `Target` are also in M31:AM53, but then loops through *all* cells in `Target`.  You should only loop over the `Target` cells which are inside the range of interest.

If you loop all `Target` cells, you might try to access (eg) `cell.Offset(0, -2)` for a cell in Column A or B...

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim trlRed As Long, adrBlue As Long, rng As Range, cell As Range
    
    trlRed = RGB(230, 37, 30)
    adrBlue = RGB(126, 199, 216)
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M31:AM53"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'only loop though any cells in M31:AM53
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If cell.Value = "Session" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Trial" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = trlRed
            ElseIf cell.Value = "AndroidSmartphone" And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "trial" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = adrBlue
            Else
                cell.Resize(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate you sincerely.  Mr. Tim 
 I appreciate your advice. Your code works perfectly. 
I've tested (e.g. delete multiple cell values, enter same character to multiple cells)several times and see no errors though , Are there any risks of error occured by this code ?
Do I have to modify  code to handle errors , for instence "On error resume next"  or anything?

Comment: When your code is not updating the sheet there's less risk (when updating the sheet you typically need to disable events to prevent a loop, and so you need error handling to ensure the events get re-enabled).   Are you really testing every cell in M3:AM53 though?  Could any cell in that range contain "Session" or "Androidsmartphone"?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will modify codes.

Comment: i want to change the range(M31:AM53) into 
the ranges below.
Sub WriteNumber_v4()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 6
For j = 1 To 7
Set rng = Range("M31:O33").Offset((i - 1) * 4, (j - 1) * 4) 'change 3 to 4
rng.Value = 1
Next j
Next i
End Sub
I appreciate your kindness and advices.

Comment: If you have code to add please edit your question and add it there (or post a new question explaining the change you want to make.